# Accessing cookies inside an iframe by a script in the same iframe

Tags: iframe, cookies

An iframe with a source in Website-A is nested on a page on Website-B.

If a user previously visited website A and had some cookies created, will those cookies be available to a script in the iframe (src=website-A)?

The parent frame (Website-B) is irrelevant. Everything is happening inside the iframe.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: The answer is yes you can. I eventually set up a test page and it works.

Comment: How did you achieve that ?